# Wordpress theme: show different number of posts on mobile?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, mobile-website

I tried making the title as descriptive as possible...
What I was wondering was; if it is possible to show a different number of posts on the front page on a mobile/handheld device..

I guess you could do some if else for the query, and user-agent would be involved somehow. but I was wondering if there is some bulletproof solution? so that no browser or mobile/handheld would reach the full version?

Comment: This website is a FAQ about programming. Your question asks for an API service that is backed up with processes that need massive interaction with the mobile devices industry. We don't do any recommendations here, but technically it works like you outlined it and that's already the whole story. - Not a recommendation: http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

Comment: thanks! the non-recommendation works great ;)

Comment: Good to hear ;) - If you find something that does not work, report back to the project over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect whether or not the user is on a mobile device on your wordpress site with the script at http://detectmobiledevices.mobi. As the article says, simply add this to your themes folder.

```
include('mobile_device_detect.php');
$mobile = mobile_device_detect();
```

You can find the original article here at: http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-detect-mobile-visitors-on-your-wordpress-blog

If you don't have a seperate mobile theme this is probably the way you'd want to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a separate mobile theme in Wordpress, you can edit the loop in that particular theme to show only however many posts you want.

This is the ideal way of doing it.

It seems as if you want to use the same Wordpress theme for both desktop and mobile, and only want to change the number of posts displayed.  I wouldn't recommend this.  Instead use a separate theme and have Wordpress display that different theme based on the user agent.

A plugin like the one I've linked to below might help you out.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mobile-detector/

Comment: @guzh Quite simply?  It's much easier to develop and maintain two different themes for a blog than trying to create a single one that works on all sizes and devices.  It makes for a much better experience.  A quick example would be something like drop down menus.  If you're theme using really cool looking drop down javascript for the desktop users...you'd obviously want a completely different system for mobile devices.  In such a case, a different theme is easier to maintain, test, and develop.  This way you can give the most optimal experience to both types of visitors; desktop and mobile.

Comment: As far as the 'How' the plugin I linked to above will allow you to select two separate themes.  One for desktop and one for mobile.  That plugin will then automatically display the proper theme based on screen size, user agent, and other details automatically. :)

Comment: Ah, okey :) Thanks. I've created a responsive theme (following the mobile-first principle), and the only difference in functionality I want between the desktop and the mobile/tablet is the amount of posts loaded. I've found a decent solution now I think ;)